# Redirect with lighttpd and fastcgi on Django App

Tags: redirect, django, lighttpd, fastcgi

I have setup my lighttpd in a fashion which redirects all subdomains to my primary domain in following fashion `* .domain.com` -> `domain.com`. Unfortunately when i type in a subdomain such as `www.domain.com` it goes directly to `http://domain.com/site.fcgi/` and literally breaks the page. When i exclude the subdomain it opens the page perfectly.

Following lighttpd settings are used:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "\.domain\.com(:[0-9]+)?$" {
            url.redirect = ("^/(.*)" => "http://domain.com/$1")
}

$HTTP["host"] =~ "^domain\.com(:[0-9]+)?$" {    
   server.document-root = "/var/www/servers/domain.com/awesomesite"
   accesslog.filename = "/var/www/logs/domain.com/access.log"
   server.errorlog = "/var/www/logs/domain.com/error.log"
   fastcgi.server = (
       ".fcgi" => (
           "main" => (
               # Use host / port instead of socket for TCP fastcgi
               "bin-path" => "/var/www/servers/domain.com/awesomesite/domain.fcgi",
               "socket" => "/tmp/domain.sock",
               "check-local" => "disable",
               )
          ),
    )
    alias.url = (
        "/static/" => "/var/www/servers/domain.com/awesomesite/static/",
    )
    url.rewrite-once = (
        "^(/static.*)$" => "$1",
        "^(/.*)$" => "/domain.fcgi$1",
    )     
}
```

Furthermore i have added `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = ''` to my `settings.py`.

I am not able to figure out where the problem is caused, there is nothing to come for in the log files either. Im a bit lost in no mans land.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url.rewrite-once` triggers before `url.redirect`, and `$HTTP["host"] =~ “domain\.com"` matches `www.domain.com` too.

So it first rewrites (for example) `http://www.domain.com/` internally to `http://www.domain.com/domain.fcgi/` and then redirects the client to `http://domain.com/domain.fcgi/`. The client sends a new request which gets then rewritten to `http://domain.com/domain.fcgi/domain.fcgi/` and then sent to the django app.

The solution is to make the second block match only "domain.com" and not the sub-domains, i.e. `$HTTP["host"] == "domain.com"` (simple comparison) or `$HTTP["host"] =~ "^domain\.com"` (anchored regular expression).

Even more strict regular expressions would be `$HTTP["host"] =~ "\.domain\.com(:[0-9]+)?$"` and `$HTTP["host"] =~ "^domain\.com(:[0-9]+)?$"`

Comment: I tried doing either of the second blocks as you described, but the behaviour is static. I even tried to delete the socks and reload, restart to be sure its not "old" data. Is there more i should do?

Comment: Looking at the `access.log` i see that when i go through a subdomain it attempts to acccess everything through the `site.fcgi` file insteader of `/` as it does with `domain.com`.

Comment: I have updated the config in my main question.

Comment: your config above uses a wrong quote. also use curl -v to test, and clear your browser cache.

Comment: I have been clearing cache all day, but i just realised that the i had not ticked the right one off the list. But fortunately i have been using Safari aswell at the same time, and it started to show the right results. I appriciate your help! Thanks.